# On the special value of Hecke L function.

Tags: number-theory, l-functions

For a nontrivial Hecke character $\chi:A_Q^{\times}/Q^{\times}\to S^1$, we know $L_Q(s,\chi)$ is nonzero. Is this true for number field $F$? I know is is holomorphic at $s=1$ by Artin conjecture, but wonders whether it is zero or not.

Thanks.